# How to detect when no fingers are on the screen?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nstimer

I need some help with the `touchesEnded` function. I want to start a `NSTimer` when there are no fingers on the screen using the `touchesEnded` function. Is this possible?. Currently I have a `touchesBegan` function working :-).

Here's my code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];

    if (numTaps >= 2)
    {
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numTaps];
        self.label2.text = @"+1";
        [self.button setHidden:YES];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (void)showButton
{
    [self.button setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, are you having trouble starting a timer? Or detecting when there aren't any touches present?

Comment: If the question is 'can I start a NSTimer?'. Yes of course.

Comment: Hello 0x7fffffff thanks for your reply :D. I'm having problems detecting when there are no touches on the screen :-/ I know how to create a NSTimer but it doesn't start if I put it in the touchesEnded function :-(

Comment: Are you trying to implement an idle timer?

Comment: Yup jrturton I want to start a timer wich tells the app that no finger are on the screen (idle) so I can trigger the showButton function :-) [don't know if you know what I mean ^^" ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tricky. You don't get an event that tells you that all fingers are up; each `touchesEnded` only tells you that this finger is up. So you have to keep track of touches yourself. The usual technique is to store touches in a mutable set as they arrive. But you can't store the touches themselves, so you have to store an identifier instead.

Start by putting a category on UITouch, to derive this unique identifier:

```
@interface UITouch (additions)
- (NSString*) uid;
@end

@implementation UITouch (additions)
- (NSString*) uid {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%p", self];
}
@end
```

Now we must maintain our mutable set throughout the period while we have touches, creating it on our first touch and destroying it when our last touch is gone. I'm presuming you have an NSMutableSet instance variable / property. Here is pseudo-code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // create mutable set if it doesn't exist
    // then add each touch's uid to the set with addObject:
    // and then go on and do whatever else you want to do
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    // remove uid of *every* touch that has ended from our mutable set
    // if *all* touches are gone, nilify the set
    // now you know that all fingers are up
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer matt! :-) Mhmm... Would an idle timer be easier to write instead of detecting fingers?

Comment: This doesn't scale across a whole app, or an interface made of multiple view controllers.

Comment: Yup I know this :-). Would an idle timer be easier?

Answer (score 2):

To create an idle timer, the simplest way is to create a custom subclass of UIApplication, and override `sendEvent:` - here, call super, and reset your timer. This will cover all touches for you. Every touch your app receives goes through this method.

To use the custom application subclass you need to modify the call in main.m to UIApplicationMain(), inserting your custom class name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't know how to do this ^^" I think I'll try matt's answer first :-)

Comment: @jrturton - Does this deal with the user performing a long press?

Comment: @rmaddy yes, all events. Perhaps if it was a _really_ long press you might have problems...

Comment: @jrturton That was my point. Why the user is holding the long press, no events would be sent. Yet with this solution, the idle timer would kick in. Of course it would get reset when the user moved or lifted their finger. So it's a matter of how long the idle timer needs to be versus how long the user sits still with a long press.

Comment: I don't know if events go or not- the touch could be moving slightly during the long press. It doesn't really seem like a very sensible use case (not your example, the whole thing)

Comment: Nope, I don't think the user will perform a long press, the app I'm developing is a simple counter with a button and the ability to count pressing twice on the screen, so it won't be a problem. Thanks for all  your replies, tho :-D